# Deleted Files exe Below Specific Size in drive c:/

Tags: vbscript

I'm looking for Deleted Files exe Below Specific Size just in drive c:/ but without Deleted Files in author folder in drive c:/

I have code vbsript work in all drive d:/ e:/ f:/ only in c:/ is not work because c:/ drive of system i think

```
'Here we set your global variables. These values
'don't change during the runtime of your script.
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sDirectoryPath = "c:\"


RecurseFolders sDirectoryPath

Sub RecurseFolders(sFolder)
  'Here we set the oFolder object, note that it's
  'variable scope is within this sub, so you can
  'set it many times and it's value will only be
  'that of the sub that's currently running.
  Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sFolder)


  'Here we are looping through every file in the
  'directory path.
  For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    'This just checks for a file size less than 450Kb
    If oFile.Size < 450000 And Right(LCase(oFile.Name),3) = "exe" Then
      oFile.Delete True
    End If
  Next

End Sub

'When calling subs you don't need to set their value
'to a variable name, and you don't use parenthesis.


'Clean up
Set oFSO = Nothing
```

Comment: try running the script with admin privileges (right click and "Run as Administrator")

Comment: "Run as Administrator" this is work just with application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run a script as administrator through another vbs call.
Here's a convenient way to have a script call itself again with privileges (it still triggers the prompt, of course)

```
Option Explicit
Dim App
Dim wsh

Set App = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
If WScript.Arguments.length =0 then
    App.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ uac", _
    "", "runas", 1
Else
    ' the main script in here
    ' ...
End If
```

So, this would be your entire script:

```
Option Explicit
Dim App
Dim wsh
Dim oFSO, sDirectoryPath

    Set App = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    If WScript.Arguments.length =0 then
        App.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", """" & WScript.ScriptFullName & """ uac", _
        "", "runas", 1
    Else
        Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        sDirectoryPath = "C:\"
        RecurseFolders sDirectoryPath
        Set oFSO = Nothing
    End If


Sub RecurseFolders(sFolder)
    dim oFolder, oFile
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sFolder)
    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
        If oFile.Size < 450000 And Right(LCase(oFile.Name),3) = "exe" Then
            oFile.Delete True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: my script in C:\WINDOWS\Delete.vbs so how i can run a script as administrator

Comment: Thank you ^^ but files exe Do not delete size 450 kb nothing changed

Comment: It deletes files which are smaller than ~ 450,000 bytes. You can change the figure in the code. It works on my computer (tested only with some ~20 KB sized .exe files). Please write full, actual sentences if you have further questions.

Comment: i try again without any Results i don't know where is problem i try change Path d: e: the same thing the script is work but nothing delete smaller than 450 kb

Comment: Well, it works here. It only works in the given folder itself, NOT in subfolders, did you understand this right? (Your copied code says 'Recurse', but there is no recursion)

Comment: i find another Solution with cmd commend the probleme is solved and thank you very match